# jquery auto double click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code when i click on loadmore button it automatically double click

this is my html

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mygallery">
                Launch demo modal
              </button>

              <!-- Modal -->
              <div class="modal" id="mygallery" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
                  <div class="modal-content" style="width: fit-content;">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body datafromdb col-md-12" id="imagesfromdb">    
                      <div class="row image-grid">

                      </div>
                      <button class="loadmore" data-id="2">Load More</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

this is my javascript

```
$(document).on('show.bs.modal','#mygallery', function () {
  var section = $('.image-grid');
  section.html('loading...');
  var page = '1';
  $.post('<?php echo base_url('Admin/getImagesApi') ?>', {
    page:page,
    check:1,
  },function (e) {
    if (e.status == 'success') {

      if (e.html !== '') {
        $('.image-grid').html(e.html);
        var btn = $(".loadmore");
        btn.show();
        btn.data("id",e.nextpage);
        btn.removeAttr('disabled');
        console.log('ok');
        btn.on('click', function () {
          btn.html('click');
          console.log(btn);

        });
      }else{
      }
      
    }else{
      section.html('End');
    }
  });
});
```

i just want when i close modal it cancel this event
OR just single click on every time when i call modal
if anyone figure out error please let me now
thanks

Comment: The problem with this code is that every time the `show.bs.modal` event occurs, the `btn.on(...)` handler is added again.  Hence a double-click, followed by a triple-click, and so on.  The `btn.on(...)` handler should be added only once outside of the code that handles the AJAX completion.

Comment: Can you fix my code please

Comment: try: `btn.off().on('click', function () {`